# Looking for a VoIP solution to integrate in a Windows store app

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, voip

I would like my Windows store app (Windows 8 + Windows rt) to **integrate** real time voice conversation with other users of the app (aka VoIP). Are there any in-app communication solution or SIP client for this?

I know about a solution for Windows Phone 8, but I'm looking for a solution for Windows 8/RT:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206983.aspx

I would be able to host a server (FreeSwitch for instance) and to pay for a product if needed. My conditions is it integrates in a Windows store app (compatible WinRT).

Comment: Do you want to communicate you app to other VOIP apps such as Skype ?

Comment: no need, just within my app is fine

Comment: did you find any solutions yet ?

Comment: No, I'm currently failing at finding/implementing a SIP client for WinRT that would connect to FreeSwitch.

Comment: I want to quote Xyroid: "did you find any solutions yet ?" ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you've already looked over the [Windows 8 Real-time communication sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Simple-Communication-Sample-eac73290)!?

If you've already checked it out please share your experience with it. I am trying to use it for a video-chat functionality of my app, but this sample is "not very mature" - to put it mildly. Good luck with your voip solution!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice this sample before. I'll give it a try.